# Error in updating apt

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

The result of sudo apt update

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: You have problems with internet connection.

Comment: or a proxy is set in your system but not for apt.